# How to attach picture to canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I have added `<input type='file' id="image">` to my HTML code. How to make this uploaded picture display on my canvas(p5js)? How to add a listener to this action and extract this added file to the canvas so I can modify it

```
enter code here
```

One of my attempts but not working:

```
    select("#img").mouseClicked(function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('img');
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = output.data;
})
```

another attempt :
  select("#img").mouseClicked(function(){
var output = document.getElementById('img');
console.log(output); // this doesnot give me a pictue as //output
image(output,10,10); //gives me error message Uncaught //TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on //'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type //'(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or //HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or //SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
//  at d.Renderer2D.image

```
})`
```

Comment: You stated `id="image"` but you are selecting "#img"`.  You should be able to test things in the browser's developer tools to see errors in the console.

Comment: thanks it is a typo here but  id="img" and  getEelementById("img")

Comment: I guess you need to explain in more detail what you want to do and share some more code. Interesting topic, I have had a look into https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mouseClicked and https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image - maybe you can even share the code of your attempt using the p5 editor (https://editor.p5js.org/).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please fix your formatting as nobody can understand your question, nor help you like this. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193325/1007648

Answer (score -2):

Found a way to make it

```
for(let i =0;i<this.colours.length;i++)
        {
            let m = color(this.colours[i]);
            let blueValue = blue(m);
            let greenValue = green(m);
            let redValue = red(m);
            this.colorArray.push([blueValue,greenValue,redValue]);
        }
```

colours[] contain colors names not as RGB now i have a new a rray contain their RGB value, needs to add alpha (slider ) using p5js

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please fix your formatting and mark this as accepted to help others who may have the same problem. Read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193325/1007648 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: There's a much better (read: propper) way of doing this. You want the readAsDataURL method of the FileReader class. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL